# OrthoMouse doesn't work in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, mouse, usb-modeswitch

I have a OrthoMouse for carpal tunnel and the mouse pointer doesn't move at all. The buttons (right, left, wheel) work fine but i can't move the pointer. The mouse works fine in windows. I have a different Microsoft optical mouse and that one works just fine in the same USB port. Is there any way to fix this? I really love my OrhtoMouse.

Comment: What is exact brand/model?  There are three or four with that name.

Comment: Can please include output from **lsusb**, which show the device attached (and its unique USB brand/model ID).

Comment: the mouse only says OrthMouse DeSagalle and on the bottom model# 099 FCC-ID V6T-099.

Comment: lsusb says: Bus 005 Device 005: ID 1d57:0005

Answer (score 0):

***PARTIAL ANSWER ONLY***

**lsusb** output of "ID **1d57:0005**" means 'USB HID v1.10 Mouse or Keyboard device'.  The 'HID' part means "Human Interface Device", which generically covers mice, keyboards, etc.

In other words, your device is **not** being recognized, and only its generic capabilities are available.  You need a Linux driver for this device.

*Will need to investigate further ..*

Comment: is there any OthoMouse that works? If yes i'll just order one of those